# Formatting DateTime to be Human Readable (Eg Messaging App)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

How can I format a DateTime binding to look exactly (or as similar as possible) like the Messaging Hub.

The following block is the code I'd ideally use to display it, or will I just need to give up and use a converter?

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Right">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding Path="Time"
                 StringFormat="*String format here?*"/>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The result I'm aiming for is as follows:

- 12:17 (Time only) if today
- Wed, 18:10 (Day + Time) if within 7 days
- 01/04, 15:58 if older than 7 days

Comment: Like they say below, you'll need to use a converter, but I highly recommend that you try writing this converter on your own. Knowing how to write converters is a key skill in Silverlight/WPF/WP7 development.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I agree they will be useful! I am looking into writing a converter. However this is not the place to do it, I just tested the DateTime converters provided by the toolkit and they perform a lot of region specific changes, I don't want to annoy users by not formatting dates how they want them!

Comment: Understandable (and a good consideration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to implement a Date to String converter which will produce the specific text you are looking for, as the amount of logic you will require is out of the scope of the StringFormat property.

For more details, in particular the ThreadDateTimeConverter :-

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-DateTime-Converters

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the DateTimeConverters from the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com)!

You can check [here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-Toolkit-DateTime-Converters) for some info over DateTimeConverters usage.